# How do you load a plugin with jqMobi?

Tags: mobile, jqmobi

I'm trying to use the actionsheet plugin with jqMobi and the overlay panel loads and the html is added to the DOM, but the animation doesn't run and I can't actually see the actionsheet.

I've included the script and link tags for the javascript file and stylesheet and confirmed that both are being loaded by the browser.

When I run the code from the api docs only the overlay is shown :s

```
$.ui.actionsheet("<a href='javascript:;' class='button'>Settings</a> <a href='javascript:;' class='button red'>Logout</a>")
```

Do I need to add the javascript and css files or are they included by default with jqMobi UI?

Comment: I'm the lead for jqMobi - care to share the "bug" you found?  I tried it inside jqUi and outside with no issues.  The only reason it would not show is if you had an overriding style yourself.

Comment: Hi Ian, my apologies...I think the "bug" ended up being something one of our developers did...jqMobi rocks :D

Comment: No problem...if there is a bug we like to here about it and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

if you aren't using jqUi, plugins are generally accessed by $(selector)._function(params)

```
$(document.body).actionsheet("<a href='javascript:;' class='button'>Settings</a> <a   href='javascript:;' class='button red'>Logout</a>")
```